# GridView update gui after remove and add items to the data collection

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, observablecollection

I'm trying to show user picked files in a GridView.
There's a strange bug (perhaps in my code) in following scenario:

- pick an image
  -> shows image in the GridView
- pick second image
  -> shows image in the GridView
- pick third image
  -> shows image in the GridView
- delete 2nd image
  -> image disappears from the GridView
- add fourth image 
  -> **the GridView shows previously deleted 2nd image (??)**
- add an extra image
  -> **the GridView shows the new image (??)**

Funny thing is, my PageModel collection contains the right data...

This is a snippet of how I'm adding items tocollection:

```
var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    var img = new BitmapImage();
    await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);

    PageModel.SelectedMedia.Add(new MyMedia
    {
        Title = file.DisplayName;
        Source = img;
    };
}
```

And this is how I remove items from the collection:

```
PageModel.SelectedMedia.Media.Remove(data as MyMedia);
```

I get the 'data' object from clicked button DataContext...

Can anyone please help me with this bug?

I don't wish to set brand new collection to the GridView each time the user adds a new file... (Plus, I lose all the fancy animations and the screen flickers)

Comment: `PageModel.SelectedMedia.Media.Remove(data as MyMedia);`? Shouldnt this be like `PageModel.SelectedMedia.Remove(data as MyMedia);`

Comment: Thank you @Stamos
That was a typo :)

Comment: Fix the typo please. From your code I cant find a reason what you say to happen. Can you post more of your Method code, MyMedia class and the xaml part of DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds like that you can't really get the selected item's data when you want to delete one, because [ObservableCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) can provide notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

You don't need to set brand new collection to the `GridView` each time the user adds a new file when using `ObservableCollection Class`.

> I get the 'data' object from clicked button DataContext...

I can't quite understand what you mean with this sentence, but according to your posted code, I wrote a small demo here, it's not complete the same as your code, but you may take a look.

XAML code of MainPage:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" Grid.Row="0">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200" Height="200" RightTapped="OnDelete">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding Source}"  Margin="20,20,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
<Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Content="Add Picture" Click="OnAdd" />
```

C# code of MainPage:

```cs
private PageModel.MyMedia MyMedia = new PageModel.MyMedia();
public ObservableCollection<MyMedia> SelectedMedia = new ObservableCollection<MyMedia>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    gridView.ItemsSource = SelectedMedia;
}

private async void OnAdd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            await img.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            SelectedMedia.Add(new MyMedia
            {
                Title = file.Name,
                Source = img
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}

private void OnDelete(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var data = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as MyMedia;
    SelectedMedia.Remove(data);
}
```

And the `MyMedia` class in the `PageModel` folder:

```cs
 public class MyMedia
 {
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public BitmapImage Source { get; set; }
 }
```

As I said, I can't really understand how you get your `data` object, but my method works fine. In this demo, you can use file picker to add images to the `GridView`, and delete the picture by right clicking one item.

Comment: Thank you, @Grace
Sorry, I couldn't reply earlier...

I'll try to explain a bit more detailed my situation... but if there's something missing or it is misleading, please reply and I can also create a small sample and share it...


I have a custom control for displaying any StorageFile user picks (It only contains 2 dependency properties: Title (string) and Source (StorageFile))

Now, this control is set as DataTemplate of my GridView.

There's also a FlyoutMenu attached to each element inside the GridView that enables users to remove a file from selection (later I plan to add other options)
.

Comment: From that FyloutMenuItem and GridView selectedIndex I can remove desired item from my collection.

The GridView behaves weird only when I remove items and try to add new ones... If I remove one item, the next item I add will not be shown - it will show the one I removed...

I hope this clarifies my problem...

Comment: @evilgugl, I'm off work now, can't program for your problem until next Monday. But it shouldn't be difficult to adapt my code to yours, it is strange that one deleted item being shown again. Maybe it's better sharing me your sample, then I will update my answer on Monday, is that OK for you?  Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Hi @Grace
I finally found time to make a sample project to demonstrate what's bothering me...
But... The funny thing is... The sample works...
So, I'm guessing I have some other problem :(

Thanks a lot for all the help